# SQL Server 2008 ssrs multiple records into one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've been reading other similar "multiple records into one" posts, but either cannot seem to get any to work, or they don't really apply to what I am trying to do.

Here are my 3 tables. vehicle, vehicle_repair, comments

- `vehicle` columns: vehicle_name and other vehicle related info,vehicle_make, vehicle_model
- `vehicle_repair` columns: vehicle_name, vehicle_repair_type, vehicle_repair_num, etc, etc
- `comments` columns: vehicle_name,vehicle_repair_num, comments_detail

The way the program is written, if I write more than 1 line of comments, it doesn't concatenate them, it makes 1 entry for each line, ie:

`comments` table:

```
vehicle_name                 vehicle_rpr_num             comments_detail
--------------------------------------------------------------------
150                           1         replaced hose
750                           1         replaced belt
750                           2         replaced fuel and also saw that the
750                           2         timing belt needs to be replaced
750                           2         as well
```

I was trying to use something like:

```
select 
    substring((select ' '+comments_detail AS 'data()' 
               from comments 
               for xml path('')), 3, 80) as 'comments_detail' 
from 
    comments
```

I tried to add the join and other tables inside the substring but then the comments_details become all jacked up, like it then combines 20 comments together instead of 1 at a time.

I'd rather start from scratch and see if I can get it working another way.

My issue comes in when I try to link the 3 tables above.

I do not know how to put in the other fields that I need from the vehicle table, ie vehicle_make, vehicle_model

Any ideas? Am I writing my concatenate completely wrong? I am trying to put this into a stored procedure, would a view be better?

Comment: Can you show the query you have used to pull this data ???

Comment: +1 for providing the sample data and showing effort

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1.vehicle_name,
       c1.vehicle_rpr_num,
       STUFF((SELECT ' ' + comments_detail
              FROM comments c2
              WHERE c2.vehicle_name = c1.vehicle_name
                    AND c2.vehicle_rpr_num = c1.vehicle_rpr_num
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),
             1,1,'')
       AS comments
FROM comments c1
GROUP BY c1.vehicle_name, c1.vehicle_rpr_num;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e494/5) with the sample `comments` data.

You were on the right track using `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate the comments. There are many different ways to concatenate, a good article on the pros/cons of each is [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/). I'd put this into a view definition to allow for easier joining with other tables.

Comment: I dont know much about views, but my vehicle related files, the ones that I would end up joining in the views, probably have a million comment lines. Will that kill my performance when running a report based off the view?

Comment: I'd be surprised if the `vehicle_name` and `vehicle_rpr_num` columns weren't part of the primary key on the `comments` table. Primary keys are usually clustered indexes, which would help your query perform better when querying for a specific `vehicle_name` or `vehicle_rpr_num`. This is a good starter [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/) on indexing if you are interested in learning more.

Comment: And to answer your question - any query that concatenates rows in this fashion will be suboptimal because you're scanning (or seeking) the `comments` table more than once, effectively doubling I/O operations. The optimal solution is to fix the application so the concatenation query doesn't have to be run. The view definition would be a stop gap until the fix can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (vehicle_name INT,vehicle_rpr_num INT,comments_detail NVARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES
(150,1,'replaced hose'),
(750,1,'replaced belt'),
(750,2,'replaced fuel and also saw that the'),
(750,2,'timing belt needs to be replaced'),
(750,2,'as well')

SELECT DISTINCT t.vehicle_name, t.vehicle_rpr_num , STUFF(List.Comments, 1 ,2, '') AS Comments
FROM tbl t
       CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT ' ' + comments_detail [text()]
                    FROM tbl
                    WHERE vehicle_name = t.vehicle_name
                    AND vehicle_rpr_num = t.vehicle_rpr_num
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    )List(Comments)
```

**Result Set**

```
vehicle_name    vehicle_rpr_num   Comments
150                     1         eplaced hose
750                     1         eplaced belt
750                     2         eplaced fuel and also saw that the timing belt needs to be replaced as well
```